# Fully Disable PrntScr Key

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard-shortcuts, console, xkb

I recently came across a Linux feature I have never seen before, where pressing the <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> button on the keyboard prints a physical piece of paper with the contents of my console.

I really need to find out how to disable this. It is driving me crazy.

I followed a guide on creating a custom keymap, and I tried remapping it to <kbd>Esc</kbd> and loading my custom keymap instead, but it didn't seem to work.  By disabling, I mean I would preferably like the key to not send any input at all, and ideally I would like to allow CUPS to continue running.

What exactly controls this behavior? And are there any specific man pages I can read about this?

**EDIT:** A little bit of additional info I should have given: I launch Openbox after logging into a TTY rather than using a DM.  I am looking for a solution that would disable printing even if I were on a TTY, since <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> prints from a TTY as well.

Comment: One might note that this is actually the very meaning of "printing your screen"... ;-)

Comment: This sounds like something that your DE, Gnome or KDE, would handle...

Comment: @ChrisDown Yes, it was obvious to me afterward what had caused a page to print haha. On my laptop, this is a bigger problem because the PrntScr key is near Backspace and a very slim Delete.

Comment: @jasonwryan I posted info about my graphical environment (no DE to speak of).  I am aware of keybinding abilities with Openbox, but since it will print while I am in a TTY as well, I would like to just disable the key itself, or change whatever handles this in the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to disable <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> on the console with a custom `keymap`. On archlinux the procedure is as follows (it should be similar for other distros):

1. `cd /usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty`
2. copy your default keymap to a new file: `cp us.map.gz personal.map.gz`
3. gunzip the new map file: `gunzip personal.map.gz`
4. edit `personal.map` using your favorite editor:
   switch to a *tty*, run `showkey` and press <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> to get the key code. On my system it outputs:

   ```
   keycode 99 press
   keycode 99 release
   ```

   so <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> code is `99`.
   Add

   ```
   keycode  99 = nul
   ```

   to `personal.map`
5. gzip the map file:  `gzip personal.map` then run `loadkeys personal` to load the custom keymap then hit <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> to test the new keymap.
6. make it permanent by (creating if not present and) editing `/etc/vconsole.conf`: replace `KEYMAP=us` with `KEYMAP=personal`.
7. reboot

The above works only on console, you will have to disable <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> also in `X`.
One way to do that is to comment it out in your `X` `keycodes` file (the one corresponding to your keyboard - linux uses `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev`). Key code is `<PRSC>`, just comment it out (add `//` in front of it) e.g. replacing

```
<PRSC> = 107;
```

with

```
// <PRSC> = 107;
```

completely disables <kbd>PrntScr</kbd>.

Comment: I didn't know I had to remap keys for X as well!  The console half seemed to work when I did it anyway.  I will assume it works, accept it, and test it when I have a little more time.  One question though: where did you find the info about X keymaps?  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GNOME I believe you can do this through `gconf-editor`.

```
$ gconf-editor
```

Then navigate the left side hierarchy like so:

```
/apps/metacity/global_keybindings
```

You'l l want to set the attribute "run_command_screenshot" to "disabled".

#### screenshot

[image: ss of gconf-editor]