# How to permanently disable the Insert key on Linux?

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard, keyboard-layout

The <kbd>Insert</kbd> is located right next to <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.
So when I am using Leafpad, Gedit, etc., I hit <kbd>Insert</kbd> by accident often, which causes the cursor to turn into a bold box which
over-writes text as I type.

How do I disable it?

Comment: What distribution of Linux are you running, what Desktop Environment are you using? And are you wanting to change this on the bash command line, or in applications such as vim?

Comment: @Drav Sloan, i am running centos linux with gnome gui desktop, i would like to disable it everywhere not application-sepecific.

Comment: If it can not be disabled, i'd like to at least disable it in gedit and leafpad applications.

Comment: i actually might just remove this button from the keyboard, pysically.

Comment: Just remap it to something else...

Comment: See also [Fully Disable PrntScr Key](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74151)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, find the keysym which corresponds to Insert

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep -i insert
```

This is probably key 118. To disable it globally run

```
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 118 ="
```

which causes that key to map to nothing at all.

Running this command every time your Xserver starts is very dependent upon which distribution and session manager you are using.