# Unmaping BKSP and RTSH in Xorg

Tags: xkb

I am trying to improve my typing habits, I have Backspace located elsewhere on my keyboard layout, but I would like to unmap the standard backspace key while I learn to use the one on my keyboard. In addition, I use right shift too much while typing, and rarely use the left shift. For the next few weeks, I would like to unmap them. I tried adding this to my xkb configuration file, however both keys still function normally.

```
    // Unmap right shift for a while, I need to learn to use left shift more
    key  <RTSH> {
            [ NoSymbol,               NoSymbol,               NoSymbol,               NoSymbol         ],
            [ NoSymbol,               NoSymbol                  ]
    };

    // Do the same for backspace
    key  <BKSP> {
            [ NoSymbol,               NoSymbol,               NoSymbol,               NoSymbol         ],
            [ NoSymbol,               NoSymbol                  ]
    };
```

Comment: How did you apply these changes to running X server?

Comment: If by "unmap" you mean _disable_ [here's how you do it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74368)...